# NIntegrate malfunction in 2D integration

Tags: numerical-integration

The value of the integral

```
(Sqrt[b]/(Sqrt[2]*Pi^(3/2)))* Integrate[Sin[Phi]*(Exp[2*b*(Sin[Phi]^2*Cos[Tht]^2)]/Erfi[Sqrt[2*b]]), {Phi, 0, Pi}, {Tht, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

is $1$ for any real `b`, and `Integrate` returns the correct result.

Yet when I'm trying to use `NIntegrate` for higher values of `b` (`b > 1600`) I receive the wrong answer of around `0.25`. For smaller values of `b` the answer is correct.
I tried various methods for numerical integration and the problem for large `b` persists. Any ideas on which `NIntegrate` methods/options could fix this?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 11.3

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

With[{b = 2000},
 AbsoluteTiming[
  (Sqrt[b]/(Sqrt[2]*Pi^(3/2)))*
   NIntegrate[Sin[Phi]*(Exp[2*b*(Sin[Phi]^2*Cos[Tht]^2)]/
       Erfi[Sqrt[2*b]]), {Phi, 0, Pi}, {Tht, 0, 2*Pi}]]]

(* {0.118116, 0.249997} *)
```

Machine precision calculations are very fast but make no guarantee of the results. You need to use arbitrary precision when machine precision gives bad results.

```
With[{b = 2000},
 AbsoluteTiming[
  Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200},
   (Sqrt[b]/(Sqrt[2]*Pi^(3/2)))*
    NIntegrate[Sin[Phi]*(Exp[2*b*(Sin[Phi]^2*Cos[Tht]^2)]/
        Erfi[Sqrt[2*b]]), {Phi, 0, Pi}, {Tht, 0, 2*Pi},
     WorkingPrecision -> 50,
     PrecisionGoal -> 10]]]]

(* {21.1923, 0.99999999999828191323299291760817283488065070532494} *)
```